# Closure not called inside object

Tags: swift

I am trying to run this simple example using a closure for learning purpose, but doesn't seem to work as I expected:

```
class Test {
    var callback: ((_ value: Int) -> Void)?

    func perform() {
        callback
    }
}

let t = Test()
t.callback = { _ in
    print("Test")
}

t.perform()
```

I was expected that `"Test"` will get printed, but apparently it's not. Can someone point what the issue is ?

Comment: You code does not compile.

Comment: I have it written in playgrounds and there is no error showing for me. Let me try it in Xcode project than.

Comment: Inside the `perform` method you may want to pass arguments to `callback`, e.g. `callback?(5)`.

Comment: So trivial, I was fooled by Playgrounds, didn't saw the error. Can u post it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the code reveals the error:

```
error: expression resolves to an unused l-value
        callback
        ^~~~~~~~
```

`callback` is just the (optional) closure, not a call to the closure.
Apparently the Playground does not complain about the unused expression.

Calling the closure with some argument fixes the problem:

```
func perform() {
    callback?(5)
}
```